# Modify new elements when they are added

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

This is done by my userscript on page load:

```
$('a.people').each(function (index, value) {
     $('<i>'+$(value).text()+'</i>').insertBefore(value);
});
```

The web app the userscript targets, adds new `$('a.people')` elements when the user does various actions.

How can I run my code for the newly added elements? Is there an event which is triggered when new elements are added to the DOM?

I don't want to use `setInterval` because the code will loop when not required and affect the performance.

Comment: How you plan to add elements ?

Comment: you need to either find an event to attach to or run a setInterval

Comment: @zuck you can use `setInterval()` or use any event handler for this.

Comment: [Delegate events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: What browsers do you need this to work with?

Comment: And do you want to know when an element is added, or modify that element when it's added? If the latter what do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to act on new elements when the target page adds them, you have two choices:

- [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/DOM_Mutation_Observers)
  or
- Polling

(Note that the older Mutation events are deprecated and not the same as mutation observers.)

In addition, you'll need to track which nodes have been done and avoid repeatedly modifying them.  There is a utility for this: [waitForKeyElements](https://gist.github.com/2625891). It uses polling and handles all the overhead.  You will not notice a page slowdown.

A **complete userscript**, suitable for Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey, that replaces your question code, using `waitForKeyElements` would be:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Italicize People entries
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

waitForKeyElements ("a.people", italicizePeople);

function italicizePeople (jNode) {
    $('<i>' + jNode.text() + '</i>').insertBefore (jNode);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much Brock! This is exactly what I was trying to implement but I couldn't get my `MutationObserver` to listen for child elements.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use **[jquery on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)** for dynamicly added elements

Comment: uh, i did not correctly understand your question. you can wrap your code inside loop in function and call it each time when new element added